How to fix vinyl window inside sealant?
The original sealant between the inside vinyl frame and the glass is failing at the bottom of each section of my single hung window. When I gently push on the glass, I can see a small gap opening between the glass and the frame. The same thing happens to the 5 single hung windows that are facing the back of my house (facing south).
2 questions where I would love to get your insights:

is this a source of air leakage? I am mostly asking out of curiosity because I've seen condensation at those specific spots in the past.
what would be the best way to fix this? and is it even worth fixing?

I am trying to reduce some air/humidity leakage in my house before the winter.
Thanks for your help!


It's probably not a source of air leakage, but it means your double pane windows are no longer double pane windows—the insulating gas has been let out.  You may be able to have a glass and window shop replace the Insulated Glass Unit in the frame, or maybe get a new IGU from the manufacturer (I bet your warranty is long expired).

Thanks @Huesmann! Is it even worth applying a bead of caulk on the inside or I shouldn't worry about it? yea I am assuming those windows have been installed 2 decades ago by the previous owner but there is no identifying information left about the manufacturer.

Caulk would seal a little bit this winter against air possibly leaking in, but the insulating performance of that pane won't be very good.  It'd be best to replace the IGU if possible.
